# Using simple maps in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating the map as follows:

```
    var employeeMap = new Object();
   addElement(employeeMap , 1, "ABC");
   addElement(employeeMap , 2, "ABCD");

    alert(getElement(employeeMap,1)); // ABC

    function addElement(map,key,value){
        map[key] = value;
        return map;
    }

    function getElement(map,key){
        return map[key];
    }
```

How to delete a key-value pair from the map ? Is setting the map[key] = null the only option ?

Thanks,
Shikha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually remove the key/value pair, use `delete`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

So you could create a function to remove elements:

```
function deleteElement(map, key)) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(key) {
        delete map[key];
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
deleteElement(employeeMap, 2);
```

**UPDATE:**

But as I'm reading, `delete` returns `true` if it's successful, and `false` only if it cannot be deleted (for several reasons). So i guess the real version would be what the other answer has:

```
function deleteElement(map, key)) {
    return (delete map[key]);
}
```

Comment: You can skip the `hasOwnProperty` test since `delete` won't remove properties from the prototype chain.

Comment: @thesystem Yeah, I started reading more of the MDN docs and realized that...was editing as you commented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `delete`:

```
delete employeeMap[1]
```

To follow the pattern of your functions:

```
function deleteElement(map,key){
    return delete map[key];
}

deleteElement(employeeMap, 1);
```